# Get list of followers and following for group of users tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to list out the usernames that a twitter user is following, and their followers in two separate .csv cells. 
This is what I have tried so far.

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

csvFile = open('ID.csv', 'w')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

users = ['AindriasMoynih1', 'Fiona_Kildare', 'daracalleary', 'CowenBarry', 'BillyKelleherTD', 'BrendanSmithTD']


for user_name in users:
    user = api.get_user(screen_name = user_name, count=200)
    csvWriter.writerow([user.screen_name, user.id, user.followers_count, user.followers_id, user.friends_id user.description.encode('utf-8')])
    print (user.id)


csvFile.close()
```

Comment: What is your output when running the program?

Comment: I get an error "'User' object has no attribute 'followers_id'" @T.Woody

Comment: Try a CRUD approach, and do `for row in user: print(row)`. From there, do `pragma table_info(myTable)` and see what the column names are. I am guessing it is a typo or the column name does not exist.

Comment: And please be a thoughful person, by coming back here and updating us on the findings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tweepy is a wrapper around the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index).

According to the Twitter API documentation, you'll need to call the [GET friends/ids](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-ids.html) to get a list of their `friends` (people they follow), and [GET followers/ids](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids) to get their `followers`.

Using the wrapper, you'll invoke those API calls indirectly by calling the corresponding method in `Tweepy`.

Since there will be a lot of results, you should use the `Tweepy Cursor` to handle scrolling through the pages of results for you.

Try the code below.  I'll leave it to you to handle the CSV aspect, and to apply it to multiple users.

```
import tweepy

access_token = "1234"
access_token_secret = "1234"
consumer_key = "1234"
consumer_secret = "1234"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.get_friends, screen_name="TechCrunch").items():
    print('friend: ' + user.screen_name)

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.get_followers, screen_name="TechCrunch").items():
    print('follower: ' + user.screen_name)
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Although I am getting a rate limit exceeded error. How would I be able to get all of the users without getting this error?

Comment: Try `api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)` ; that will tell Tweepy to pause until the rate limit expires, instead of giving an error.

Comment: Tweepy now has ```api.get_friends``` instead of ```api.friends``` . Source: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.get_friends